# Foreach inside If isset not working PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, select, drop-down-menu, foreach

I have a select html tag. I need to display the option values depends on the job title in input text. E.g. If the job title is accounting, the list of locations for accounting will be displayed in the option values.

But my code is not working. Please help me to fix this :(

```
<select name="locations_list" id="filterbyhiringlocation">
    <option name="default" class="filter_by" selected="selected" value="Select by Location">Select by Location</option>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['jobTitle']) && $_POST['jobTitle'] == 'Sales Associate'){
        foreach($query_hiring_location_mass as $option){
            echo '<option name="locations_list" class="filter_by" selected value="'. $option->hiring_location .'">'. $option->hiring_location .'</option>';
        } else {
            echo '<option name="locations_list" class="filter_by" value="'. $option->hiring_location.'">'. $option->hiring_location .'</option>';
        }
    } else if(isset($_POST['jobTitle']) && $_POST['jobTitle'] == 'District Manager'){
        foreach($query_hiring_location_non_mass as $option){
            echo '<option name="locations_list" class="filter_by" selected value="'. $option->hiring_location .'">'. $option->hiring_location .'</option>';
        } else {
            echo '<option name="locations_list" class="filter_by" value="'. $option->hiring_location.'">'. $option->hiring_location .'</option>';
        }
    }
        ?>
</select>
```

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)
```

Comment: `else` statement always use with `if` not with `foreach` and here you are using `else` with `foreach`

Comment: what is the proper way? if the job title is equal to accounting, the location list for that job title will be display in the option values and if not accounting, the location list for not accounting will be display in option values using 1 select html tag only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

```
<?php
$hiring_location = 'YOUR DEFAULT LOCATION';
?>
<select name="locations_list" id="filterbyhiringlocation">
    <option name="default" class="filter_by" selected="selected" value="Select by Location">Select by Location</option>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['jobTitle']) && $_POST['jobTitle'] == 'Sales Associate'){
        if(count($query_hiring_location_mass)) {
            foreach($query_hiring_location_mass as $option){
                echo '<option name="locations_list" class="filter_by" selected value="'. $option->hiring_location .'">'. $option->hiring_location .'</option>';
            }
        }
        else {
            echo '<option name="locations_list" class="filter_by" value="'. $hiring_location.'">'. $hiring_location .'</option>';
        }
    } else if(isset($_POST['jobTitle']) && $_POST['jobTitle'] == 'District Manager'){
        if(count($query_hiring_location_non_mass)) {
            foreach($query_hiring_location_non_mass as $option){
                echo '<option name="locations_list" class="filter_by" selected value="'. $option->hiring_location .'">'. $option->hiring_location .'</option>';
            }
        }
         else {
            echo '<option name="locations_list" class="filter_by" value="'. $hiring_location.'">'. $hiring_location .'</option>';
        }
    }
        ?>
</select>
```

Comment: in `$hiring_location` i will put the select query to get the location list right?

Comment: What if you dont have a locations in your db... if you don't want to show default location then just delete the else condition. I assumed that default location e.g. Mumbai, Pune etc . Do not write the query in it.

Answer (score 1):

your code should like this :

```
<select name="locations_list" id="filterbyhiringlocation">
    <option name="default" class="filter_by" selected="selected" value="Select by Location">Select by Location</option>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['jobTitle']) && $_POST['jobTitle'] == 'Sales Associate'){
        foreach($query_hiring_location_mass as $option){
            if ($option->hiring_location == $yourLocation) {
                echo '<option name="locations_list" class="filter_by" selected value="'. $option->hiring_location .'">'. $option->hiring_location .'</option>';
            } else {
                echo '<option name="locations_list" class="filter_by" value="'. $option->hiring_location.'">'. $option->hiring_location .'</option>';
            }
        }
    } else if(isset($_POST['jobTitle']) && $_POST['jobTitle'] == 'District Manager'){
        foreach($query_hiring_location_non_mass as $option){
            if ($option->hiring_location == $yourLocation) {
                echo '<option name="locations_list" class="filter_by" selected value="'. $option->hiring_location .'">'. $option->hiring_location .'</option>';
            } else {
                echo '<option name="locations_list" class="filter_by" value="'. $option->hiring_location.'">'. $option->hiring_location .'</option>';
            }
        }
    }
        ?>
</select>
```

Here `$yourLocation` should be as per your requirement i.e, which you want to show selected

Comment: so i will define a query in this `$yourLocation` variable?

Comment: no.`$yourLocation` is that location which you want to show selected. for example `New York` (use dynamically as per your requirement)

Comment: yes, the hiring location is from the database table, so i need to perofm a query before i display it dynamically in the option values. like this $query_hiring_location_non_mass = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT DISTINCT hiring_location FROM resume_location WHERE hiring_location = "Utah" ORDER BY hiring_location ASC', OBJECT);

Answer (score 0):

@user i think you missed two flower bracket to close the loop use this instead:

```
    if(isset($_POST['jobTitle']) && $_POST['jobTitle'] == 'Sales Associate'){
        foreach($query_hiring_location_mass as $option){
            echo '<option name="locations_list" class="filter_by" selected value="'. $option->hiring_location .'">'. $option->hiring_location .'</option>';
} 
       } else {
            echo '<option name="locations_list" class="filter_by" value="'. $option->hiring_location.'">'. $option->hiring_location .'</option>';
        }
    } else if(isset($_POST['jobTitle']) && $_POST['jobTitle'] == 'District Manager'){
        foreach($query_hiring_location_non_mass as $option){
            echo '<option name="locations_list" class="filter_by" selected value="'. $option->hiring_location .'">'. $option->hiring_location .'</option>';
        }
} else {
            echo '<option name="locations_list" class="filter_by" value="'. $option->hiring_location.'">'. $option->hiring_location .'</option>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: how can I get `$option->hiring_location` in `else` statement

Comment: @Ranjith remove the flower brackets from the loop and try lets see what response you get. eg: `foreach($query_hiring_location_non_mass as $option)
            echo '<option name="locations_list" class="filter_by" selected value="'. $option->hiring_location .'">'. $option->hiring_location .'</option>';
        
} else {
            echo '<option name="locations_list" class="filter_by" value="'. $option->hiring_location.'">'. $option->hiring_location .'</option>';
        }`